# A generic error occurred in GDI+ error when taking a screenshot

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code I have written is below, and I get this error:

`A generic error occurred in GDI+`

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(100, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);


    bitmap.Save("@file.bmp");
}
```

Comment: What line does it occurr on?

Comment: [`Link1`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4671449/1577396) and [`Link2`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3009163/1577396)

Answer (score 1):

Because the asp.net is running as a service, and did not have access to a monitor - to the screen - actually did not have where to copy from when you call the `CopyFromScreen`

I hope from the other hand to not have mix the code that running on server and the code that running on client and believe that the CopyFromScreen is going to copy the clients screen, because this code is not running on clients computer.